Shopify bulk operation to get products associated to a particular collection
The following graphql query produces a jsonl file containing all the products
    query = '''
    mutation {
        bulkOperationRunQuery(
        query : """
            {
                products {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id
                            title
                            vendor
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        """
        ){
        bulkOperation {
                id
                status
        }
        userErrors {
            field
            message
        }
    }
}'''
shopify.GraphQL().execute(query)

How to get only the products that are associated with a particular collection?
@david lazar:
mutation {
  bulkOperationRunQuery(
   query: """
    {
      collection(id: "gid://shopify/Collection/265856909370")  {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            id
            handle
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
    """
  ) {
    bulkOperation {
      id
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}

  
{"bulkOperationRunQuery":{"bulkOperation":null,"userErrors":[{"field":["query"],"message":"Invalid bulk query: Field 'edges' doesn't exist on type 'Collection'"},{"field":["query"],"message":"Invalid bulk query: Field 'pageInfo' doesn't exist on type 'Collection'"}]}}


It is really easy. Set your sights on the collection! If you ask for a collection, you'll note that that connection comes with a products attribute! So instead of asking for products that belong to a collection, you instead ask the collection for its products. You see the difference?

I am not sure your response makes sense. I am not requesting the collection node but a mutation on the bulkOperationRunQuery. See my updated question.

Your mutation is what makes no sense. Your exact question, from you, here again:
How to get only the products that are associated with a particular collection?
So I will explain it to you again since you missed it the first time. A collection has products. So you use the collection as your root node. Asking for products and then further, restricting them to a collection is wrong. OK? You grok now?

But I must use the bulk operation, otherwise I can't get all products without handling the paging. I know how to get products of a collection, but I want to get them using the bulk operation node. Get it?

I get yes. My first answer to you was correct yet you have not understood that twice now. I am so generous I will give you a third try. Setup your bulk operation to get your Collection.products. Get it?

Thanks for your generosity, but no result till now. Did you see my updated question, I already tried what you say, but it returns an error

The fact that you cannot make a bulk query is the real issue. You can always start a new question based on that. Now that you understand the correct approach I have you. GraphQL basics with Shopify are developed decently in the docs, but they could be improved.

From the begining, I stated in the title and in the question, that I am looking for the bulk operation query. I was sure you were wasting my time and you just did. Haha

Well, happily for you, your lack of understanding will ensure you have plenty of questions for yourself in the future, keeping life interesting. Enjoy the puzzles.

It's not a lack of understanding, but a lack of knowledge. Different. Thanks for your help anyway.
